# What technique is used to create a div limited by the page fold?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Skipping the discussion about the importance of the fold in web design, I'd like to know which technique is used to limit a specific section (could be a div, for example) exactly on the browser fold considering a responsive design. Some websites even use both the mouse scroll and the a button to slide to the section below.

Ex.: [Next](http://yaynext.com/)

My point is not the slide itself, but how each section renders exactly on the fold regardless of the monitor resolution.

Comment: What do you mean by "fold"?

Comment: @JacobGray - usually they are talking about the area that is below the viewport for the webpage (its usually referred to as the 'fold')

Comment: The "above the fold" concept borrowed by the graphic design, when the content is located in the visible part of the browser without the user having to scroll. With an absolute measure like pixels it can be easily done by applying a hight, however, it's fixed and would not work for all resolutions.

Comment: Ahh, so he means that each section is the size of the viewport?

Comment: The Next site seems to use https://github.com/n33/skel for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the css unit of measurement `vh`. Say you have a `div` that you only want to take up half the screen (viewport) you would do something like this:

```
div{
    height: 50vh;
}
```

`vh` stands for "Viewport Height" and is used like a percentage. So to have the div always take up 100% of the view-able area (viewport), regardless of the screen size or resolution you would do this: `div { height: 100vh; }`

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
window.innerHeight
```

You can know the height of the browser window and style your elements accordingly.

I am assuming that by fold you mean what you see without scrolling.

If you need a more backwards compatible `(<I.E9)` height and you can use jquery:

```
$( window ).height();
```

Comment: @JGSouthern if you're using jquery there are lots of libraries that can help you.

Comment: In fact I'm learning learning the basics of jquery in order to dive deeper into them, that's why the "beginner question". By the way, any advice on learning materials? It's a long way, after all. :)

Comment: I haven't done it myself but have tried similar coursesand they were good http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery

Answer (score 0):

I would use `document.documentElement.clientHeight` and `document.documentElement.clientWidth` which are essentially the width and height of the `html` element:

```
$('div').css({'height':document.documentElement.clientHeight+'px',
              'width':document.documentElement.clientWidth+'px'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1wsLc2c/1/

You would have to re-execute this code every time the window is resized to keep the bottom of the box flush with the page fold.